# como saber el valor de un id dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo este código

```
$i=0;
             $n=0;
             while($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                 $this->empleados[]=$filas;
                 $Filas = consult_cedula($fila['Persona']);

                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo '<td>' . $Filas['codsucursal'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $fila['Persona'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $fila['Fecha'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $fila['Hora'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $Filas['nombre'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $Filas['cargo'] . '</td>';

                echo '<td>' . '<input type="button" name="nom' . $n .'" id="btn"' . $i .'" class="btn btn-danger" value="..." data-fech="' .
                  $fila['Fecha'] . '" data-hora="' . $fila['Hora'] . '" data-ced="' . $fila['Persona'] .
                  '" data-nom="' . $Filas['nombre'] . '" data-cargo="' . $Filas['cargo'] . '">';

                 echo "</tr>";


                 $i=$i+1;
                 $n=$n+1;

             }
             echo $i;
```

Esa consulta solo me va a listar 5 personas. `$i` es el id autoincrementable. Le doy un `echo $i` para probar si todo esta en orden y sí, todo en orden. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo hago para capturar el id de cada persona de forma dinámica con jquery?

Comment: buenas: revisa el <td> en el que creas el boton. En el id te esta cerrando la comilla doble antes del id, te debe estar creando un boton con id=btn"aser.  Podrias añadir un data-id = $i, para que luego tu jquery busque los data-id y pueda obtenerlos.

Comment: depende que quieras hacer con el id, como dice @Jakala podes usar un atributo `data-id` o en el script que procesa el id descartas el `btn` que le agregaste con php

Comment: pues, lo que quiero hacer es insertar el registro con capturando el valor del id

Comment: ademas, al presionar el boton, me haga la insersion de todos los campos que me devuelve la consulta. pero, no he logrado capturar el valor de $i con javascript

Comment: Disculpa pero algo anda mal, si $i es el id, ¿qué ocurrirá si elimino un usuario y lo vuelvo a insertar? habrá un desplazamiento de ids y entonces no podrás usarlo ya que el id de un registro, no será siempre el mismo. Ya que usas el atributo data, coloca el id real de la base de datos en el tr y así, podrás acceder a él.